# postgresql, pgadmin error RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I made a function like this

```
create or replace function get_source2(TableName character varying)
returns setof integer as
$$
declare
    geom geometry;
    snode integer;
begin
    execute ('select get_source(geom) from '|| TableName)
        into snode;
    return snode;
end
$$
language plpgsql;
```

output data would be array type

so I try to use `setof`.

If I don't use `setof`, it runs well but only one result comes out.

However if I use `setof`
I get an error like that

```
error : RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Be careful! The way your function is written it is vulnerable to SQL injection!

You should use

```
$$BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT get_source(geom) FROM '
                        || quote_ident(TableName);
END;$$
```

Then `RETURNS SETOF integer` will work well.

Read up in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) how to use `RETURN` in a table function:

Either you do

```
RETURN NEXT expression1;
RETURN NEXT expression2;
...
RETURN;
```

or

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT ...;
```

or

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT ...';
```

but never

```
RETURN expression;
```